# VB.NET Generic interface, base derived classes and factory pattern

Tags: vb.net, generics, factory

Hi I have problem with creating factory pattern for generic interface.

I have IFileHelper(Of T) interface:

```
Public Interface IFileHelper(Of T)

   Property ContainsHeader As Boolean

   Function IsValid(path As String) As FileValidationResult

   Function ReadFile(path As String) As List(Of T)

End Interface
```

There I have CsvFileHelper(Of T) which have implementation of interface IFileHelper(Of T)

```
Public Class CsvFileHelper(Of T)
   Implements IFileHelper(Of T)

       Public Property ContainsHeader As Boolean Implements IFileHelper(Of T).ContainsHeader

       Public Function IsValid(path As String) As Boolean Implements IFileHelper(Of T).IsValid

       End Function

       Public Function ReadFile(path As String) As List(Of T) Implements IFileHelper(Of T).ReadFile

       End Function

End Class
```

Now I have abstract class called FileModel.

```
    Public MustInherit Class FileModel

    End Class
```

And other model classes which inherits abstact class:

```
    Public Class CarModel
       Inherits FileModel
       'fields and propeties
    End Class

    Public Class TruckModel
       Inherits FileModel
       'fields and properties
    End Class

Public Shared Function FileFactory(Of FileModel)(ByVal vehicle As VehicleType) As IFileHelper(Of FileModel)

        Select Case vehicle 

            Case VehicleType.Car
                Return CType(New CsvFileHelper(Of CarModel), IFileHelper(Of FileModel))

            Case VehicleType.Truck
                Return CType(New CsvFileHelper(Of TruckModel), IFileHelper(Of FileModel))

            Case Else
                Throw New NotImplementedException("Not implemented for type " & vehicle.ToString.Trim & "!")

        End Select

    End Function
```

Main method:

```
Public Sub Main()
 Dim fileHelper As IFileHelper(Of FileModel) = FileFactory(Of FileModel)(VehicleType.Car)
End Main
```

I was set Option Strict to Off but that doesn't help, is there any way to make this thing work?

EDIT:
I edited and used factory method which @jmcilhinney showed in his answer but I got runtime error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'CsvFileHelper`1[CarModel]' to type 'IFileHelper`1[FileModel]'
```

Comment: You have to include variance allowance on your interface in order to make use  of it later.  That is, `IFileHelper` must be declared `Of In T` or `Of Out T` (I forget which one is right for your use case---the MSDN docs on covariance and contravariance should explain which one is correct).